# How to interpolate by copying values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have hourly data and I need to interpolate it to 10 minutes data by simply repeating the values:

```
data=[('2014-02-24 16:00:00', 55)
,('2014-02-24 17:00:00', 40)
,('2014-02-24 18:00:00', 68)]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['DateTime','Value'])
```

I need to get the following result:

```
DateTime                  Value
2014-02-24  16:00:00      55
2014-02-24  16:10:00      55
2014-02-24  16:20:00      55
...
2014-02-24  17:00:00      40
2014-02-24  17:10:00      40
2014-02-24  17:20:00      40
...
```

I know that it's possible to resample data in this way `minutes=df.resample('10Min',on='DateTime').mean()`.

But how can I do the simple interpolation shown above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Resampler.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) working with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

minutes=df.set_index('DateTime').resample('10Min').ffill()

print (minutes)
                     Value
DateTime                  
2014-02-24 16:00:00     55
2014-02-24 16:10:00     55
2014-02-24 16:20:00     55
2014-02-24 16:30:00     55
2014-02-24 16:40:00     55
2014-02-24 16:50:00     55
2014-02-24 17:00:00     40
2014-02-24 17:10:00     40
2014-02-24 17:20:00     40
2014-02-24 17:30:00     40
2014-02-24 17:40:00     40
2014-02-24 17:50:00     40
2014-02-24 18:00:00     68
```